# Can a callback have parameters defined?

Tags: javascript

I know it's maybe an fairly easy basic knowledge for you, here I need to ask your help to see whether there is a 'hole' behind to improve. Please check the code below, can I set 'response' as callback parameter but not callSvc's? instead of this kinda 'tricky' way?

```
function callSvc(response, callback){
    callback(response);
}

callSvc("I'm a response!",function(param_response){document.write(param_response);});
```

Thanks..

**Update**

Maybe this is good enough?

```
function callSvc(callback) {
    callback("response");
}
callSvc(function(data) {
    document.write(arguments[0]);
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to call `callback` on its own without first calling `callSvc`?

Comment: @Marcus right.. like closure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything tricky about [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) in javascript.  They are a language feature.

You can avoid the wrapping callSvc function as well, and jump straight into this:

```
var response = "I'm a response"

var callback = function(){document.write(response);};
```

The callback function can "see" response as if you passed it as a parameter, since it forms a closure.

```
callback();  //I'm a response
```

Comment: I might expressed with a bad sample. I need a wrapper with a paramater-defined callback..

Answer (score 1):

Eh? All that code looks to be the equivalent of

```
document.write("I'm a response!");
```

So you can bypass all the methods. You can also declare an anonymous function and call it immediately, if that's what you wanted to do:

```
(function(param_response){document.write(param_response);})("I'm a response!");
```

Or lastly, if you need to pass parameters to a callback that doesn't except any, then wrap it in an anonymous funciton

```
func_that_takes_callback(function(){the_real_callback(arg);});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining your callback anonymously define it before hand:

```
function callSvc(response, callback){
    callback(response);
}

function cb(param_response) {
    document.write(param_response);
}
```

Then you can use it in a call to `callSvc` or on its own:

```
callSvc("I'm a response!", cb);

cb("I'm a response!");
```